# Using PHP to import CSV data into mySQL, Part 2

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Following up on my last thread. Trying to import a user-generated CSV into MySQL via a PHP upload script. Uploads successfully, but I am not able to use LOAD DATA due to a permissions problem. Here is what I am trying to do instead:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($target_path, "r")) !== FALSE) 
  {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
     $num = count($data);
     echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
     $row++;
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
 {
  $fullRow = $fullRow . $data[$c] . "," ;
 }
 echo $fullRow;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES ('$fullRow')");
$fullRow = NULL;
}
   fclose($handle);
  }
```

`echo $fullRow` spits out a verbatim copy of the line from the CSV file, except for an additional comma on the end. Is this why the Insert is not working correctly? When I do a manual upload via phpMyAdmin, the CSV file is imported without issue. Or is there a problem with the `VALUE ('$fullRow')` bit of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the last comma.

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
 {
  $fullRow = $fullRow . $data[$c] . "," ;
 }
 echo $fullRow;
 $fullRow = substr($fullRow,0,-1);
```

And also you script is not ok.

```
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO foo (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES ('$fullRow') " );
$fullRow = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Paolo_NL_FR's fixes should get you up and running. The script could use some TLC though, and does not have even basic sql injection protection. Try something like this perhaps:

```
if (($handle = fopen($target_path, "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $values = implode(",", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data));
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES ($values);");
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```